# Template is missing Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following error:

```
Template is missing

Missing template clients/search, application/search with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

I've got a _search.html.erb file in my views folder but I'm not sure why its not working when I press the search button on my clients page.

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="client-search">
    <%= render(:partial=>'/search',:locals=>
               { :my_path => "/clients/search" })%>
</div>
```

**_search.html.erb** (file placed in views folder)

```
<%= form_tag my_path do %>
    <h6>Search Customer</h6>
    <%= text_field_tag :search_string %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

**clients_controller.rb**

```
  def search
    @clients = Client.simple_search(params[:search_string])
    render :actions => "index"
  end
```

Any chance someone could help me as to why I can't search for any clients?

Comment: `render :actions` needs to be `render :action` (singular)

Comment: I think it will be render action: :index

Comment: Cheers guys! That seems to have done the job :D

Answer (score 0):

As [Yule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858892/template-is-missing-ruby-on-rails#comment86733087_49858892) suggested `render :actions` should be singular like:

```
render :action => "index"
```